# how to find out mac addresses of all machines on network

Tags: linux-networking, find, grep, sed, awk

Is there some easy way to find out mac address of all machines on my network rather than doing an SSH into each and `ifconfig | grep HWaddr` if there are 300 machines on network I really need some easy solution.

Comment: For the sake of completeness:

    arp -n 0.0.0.0

Where 0.0.0.0 is the ip address of the device. Note that you'll still have search one at a time. Sometimes you only want one, and this is certainly faster than sshing to each box. What if it's a Windows box or printer?

Comment: sudo arp-scan --localnet

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [nmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) to run a ping scan.

```
nmap -sP 192.168.254.*

Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-03-09 11:32 GMT
Host xyzzy.lan (192.168.254.189) is up (0.00022s latency).
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:5B:A5:E0 (VMware)
Host plugh.lan (192.168.254.196) is up (0.00014s latency).
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:2E:78:F1 (VMware)
Host foo.lan (192.168.254.200) is up.
Host bar.lan (192.168.254.207) is up (0.00013s latency).
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:2D:94:A0 (VMware)
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 3.41 seconds
```

Edit:

A sed script to filter the output to IP -> MAC - put this in a file.

```
/^Host.*latency.*/{
    $!N
    /MAC Address/{
        s/.*(\(.*\)) .*MAC Address: \(.*\) .*/\1 -> \2/
    }
}  
/[Nn]map/d
s/^Host .*is up/& but MAC Address cannot be found/
```

and use it like this

```
nmap -sP 192.168.254.0/20 | sed -f sedscript
192.168.254.189 -> 00:0C:29:5B:A5:E0
192.168.254.196 -> 00:0C:29:2E:78:F1
Host foo.lan (192.168.254.200) is up but MAC Address cannot be found.
192.168.254.207 -> 00:0C:29:2D:94:A0
```

Comment: yes this is what I was looking for,  I read other messages also it is not a Cisco switch any how thanks all for the messages.

Comment: I've found that the only way to get the mac addresses to show up is to run nmap as root. Also it appears that the sedscript no longer works. [The text near the ip address has changed.

Comment: Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.147
Host is up (0.00045s latency).
MAC Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

Answer (score 16):

Use nmap. Important to run it as root so you get the MAC addresses. Example:

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

Will scan 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255. Look up CIDR notation on wiki if you're not familiar with this subnet notation.

You should be able to get nmap from the repos of any recentish Linux distro, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

or

```
sudo yum install nmap
```

A sample output from my network:

```
Host 192.168.1.1 is up (0.0069s latency).
MAC Address: 00:0D:54:9B:D8:F4 (3Com)
Host 192.168.1.78 is up (0.0068s latency).
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:BC:3D:1C (VMware)
Host 192.168.1.91 is up (0.0038s latency).
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:8A:F4:A3 (VMware)
Host 192.168.1.92 is up (0.0039s latency).
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:65:60:5F (VMware)
Host 192.168.1.158 is up (0.033s latency).
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:82:24:EA (VMware)
Host 192.168.1.186 is up (0.0024s latency).
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:3E:26:1F (VMware)
Host 192.168.1.190 is up (0.0066s latency).
```

Comment: yes your method is quite simple way.

Answer (score 10):

Try this command:

```
arp-scan --interface=eth0 192.168.1.0/24
```

Comment: I know this is a really old question. However, nmap didn't give me any MAC addresses.   arp-scan did.  Thanks.

Comment: @MikeP In my case, `nmap` only gave me MAC addresses, while `arp-scan` gave me both MAC addresses and IP addresses.

Answer (score 7):

As long as you run this command from a host in the same network segment, `nmap` will report all of the MAC address for each host is discovers.

For example:

```
sudo nmap 192.168.1.0/24 -sP

Starting Nmap 4.76 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-03-09 06:29 EST

Host old.net (192.168.1.1) appears to be up.
MAC Address: 00:18:39:C5:A1:DC (Cisco-Linksys)
```

For the MAC addresses I need to be root on my Ubuntu box. Also a simple method for a single host is just to ping it and look at the arp table with `arp -a` if you wanted to only use commands normally included in the initial install of a distribution:

```
arp -a | grep -v incomplete
foo.net (192.168.1.145) at 00:0d:4b:6a:2c:cb [ether] on eth0
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your LAN topology, your best shot may be to display the MAC address table on your switches.

So for example, if your switch infrastructure is Cisco, you may try a

```
sh mac address-table
```

on every switch.

If you have many switches, you may automate this task through the use of [SNMP](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094a9b.shtml).

Another option and (again) depending on your topology and your type of networking equipment, you may also try to get the mac addresses of your devices displaying the arp table on your routers.

With either of this two methods you will also obtain the list of mac addresses of any devices that are connected to your network infraestructure: PCs, printers, access points, etc. In the first case, even of devices without an IP address. This may or may not be want you want, but it may worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe arp-scan is also an option:

See for a example here:
[Arp-scan User Guide](http://www.nta-monitor.com/wiki/index.php/Arp-scan_User_Guide)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned about ssh into machines in your network, you can also use this shorty:

```
nmap -p 22 10.100.10.0/24 >/dev/null ; arp -a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program called SIW, it's free and scans the network requiring no permissions, or args.

URL: http://www.gtopala.com/

Available in .exe, or full installation.

Comment: .exe? The tag says "Linux-Netowrking"